# Reference to policy #AddressingPolicy could not be resolved error

Tags: java, apache, client, cxf

I am developing a web service client using Apache CXF 2.5.0 , JDK 7 and Eclipse Helios EE.
I am getting the folllowing error when I execute the web service client in eclipse.

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Reference to policy #AddressingPolicy could not be resolved..

I have followed the below steps so far to deploy the client.

1. Created a java project in eclipse helios EE and added CXF runtime to the project.
2. Using Apache CXF 2.5.0 WSDL2Java generated the java classes for the client ( included -exsh true option to process the headers). The classes were generated in the eclipse src dir.
3. Implemented the main method in the client class to invoke the web service.

When I execute the client I get the above exception.

I have checked the WSDL and it has one Policy Reference element with xml id = #AddressingPolicy and another Policy Reference element with xml id = #TlsPolicy within the binding element. The respective policies are given in the WSDL at the end of the WSDl using wsp:Policy elements.

I cannot modify the WSDL as it has been already deployed as a external service and provided to me to develop the client.

Has anyone faced similar issue with Apache CXF 2.5.0 before. Also I feel it could be an issue with the version of CXF I am using. Does Apache CXF 2.5.0 support local policy references within the WSDL.

Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.  The fix I found was to modify the WSDL and use an **wsu:Id** reference instead of **xml:id**.

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="AddressingPolicy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <...>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I know you stated that you can't change the WSDL, but I believe this is not true.  The modification I have mentioned will not change the contents of the SOAP requests/responses on the wire so you should still be able to interoperate with the existing web service.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with this change and let u know.

Comment: I tried with the above change to the WSDL but I still get the same error as before at the time of service creation by CXF. Now my WSDL for the addressing policy looks like this.